# Issues with 10GB RAM on ASUS P5E3 Premium

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3

I currently have this motherboard: Asus P5E3_Premium WiFi AP_n
and I have 2GB (2 x 1GB modules) installed in there already : Corsair-XMS3-DHX-DDR3-1333

I have purchased 2 x 4GB kit of these: GeIL Enhance 8GB (2 x 4GB) 1333MHz PC3 10660 DDR3 Memory Module

When I installed the additional memory the computer doesnt do anything. Not even a BIOS screen. When I take out the new memory it works fine.

I'm sure the old and new RAM sticks are similar in spec.
Can anyone think of a reason why this wouldnt work or am I just unlucky and received a pair of non working RAM sticks?

Took out the old sticks and put the new sticks in their place.
put the new sticks in the other 2 channels
put in each stick 1 by 1 
i know all 4 channels works because I have tried all 4 channels with old sticks.

I've reset the bios to defaults too.

Can't think of anything else to try.
As far as I am aware, it should all just work.
Even though the motherboard says it only supports 8GB max (4 x 2GB sticks) I have read that people have put in 4GB sticks in with no issues.

I have tried with just 1 of the new 4gb sticks and 2 of them making it a max of 8GB

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that what you've heard is wrong, if the motherboard clearly states that it supports 8GB (4x2GB) max.

Comment: `Even though the motherboard says it only supports 8GB max (4 x 2GB sticks) I have read that people have put in 4GB sticks in with no issues.` - Modifying your computer based on something someone posted on a Yahoo message board (that contradicts the manufacturer) is the first step down the road to failure.

Comment: @JoshR Sometimes motherboards have advertised support limits because that's the maximum memory density that was available at the time the motherboard was tested. But if no motherboard that uses that chipset supports a particular memory configuration after that configuration has been around for awhile, odds are the chipset is not physically capable of it.

Comment: What version of the BIOS are you using? Is it the latest? https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5E3_PremiumWiFiAP_n/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: yep, using the latest bios but still not being picked up.  I might have a faulty board now because if i swap around the memory sticks that were already in there it doesnt boot up either.

Answer (score 1):

"Even though the motherboard says it only supports 8GB max (4 x 2GB sticks) I have read that people have put in 4GB sticks in with no issues."

I can't see how that's possible with this motherboard. The X48 chipset, which this motherboard uses, [has an 8GB limit](http://ark.intel.com/products/35143/Intel-82x48-Memory-Controller-Hub). Also, it doesn't support 4GB sticks, you need a P45 or newer.

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/319911-30-asus-p5e3-motherboard-ddr3-module-compatibility

Comment: http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1520092

Comment: In the x48 chipset datasheet on page 33 under memory address map it states "The MCH supports a maximum of 8 GB of DRAM. No 
DRAM memory will be accessible above 8 GB." - does this mean that it can have bigger sticks?

Comment: It means exactly what it says -- the MCH can address a maximum of 8 GB of DRAM. (That's not the only chipset limitation, but that's an important one.)

Comment: I am reading so much contradicting accounts - http://www.overclock.net/t/1231879/x48-and-lga775-does-support-16gb-of-ram